# Spring MVC - How to manage Reference Data on Web Clients

Tags: spring, web-services, hibernate, architecture

I have a Typical SOA web application which has the following components as expected.

1. **The Web Client** - Sprinv MVC
2. **SOAP Services** - Spring

The Reference Data is centralized which is exposed thru its own SOAP Services.

The SOAP webservice responses have codes for elements(like CountryCode, CityCode etc).

I need the suggestions as to what should be the best approach to for ex display the Country Description instead of the country code (which needs another SOAP call to reference data and same with other codes) on the web page ?

**Few options are like:**

1. Write a custom tag library which would do the necessary calls and get the data.
2. Fetch all the ReferenceData descriptions and put it into some kind of HashMap, add it to the model to be consumed by the web page.

Any other better ways please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's reference data, no one expect it to change very often, right? Retrieve them once and serve them up using @ModelAttribute. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147921/in-spring-mvc-can-i-have-a-stateful-dropdown-with-a-backing-object).

Spring MVC is still server side, so it can handle very large data e.g. all the street addresses in US. You simply need to make sure you add some sort of filter if you don't want to serve the entire collection. And simply partial update these reference data with the latest on regular basis.